# Loading and Converting a HBITMAP to an OpenGL Texture

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, bitmap, hbitmap

I want to load a HBITMAP from a resource file and use it as an OpenGL texture. The code I use:

```
HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(hInstance, 
            MAKEINTRESOURCE(id), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
BITMAP BM;
GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(BM), &BM);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
GLvoid* bits = BM.bmBits;
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, BM.bmWidth,
        BM.bmHeight, 0, GL_BGRA_EXT,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        bits);
```

But I allways get an error from Visual Studio that I dont have access to the pointer `bits`. The error is at the last line of code:

```
bits);
```

I actually can use the NULL pointer instead of `bits` without getting an error. I can output `bits` to using a messagebox. Does anybody have an idea what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`GetObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation:

> If *`hgdiobj`* is a handle to a bitmap created by any other means, `GetObject` returns only the width, height, and color format information of the bitmap. You can obtain the bitmap's bit values by calling the `GetDIBits` or `GetBitmapBits` function.

In context, "other means" is anything other than `CreateDIBSection`.  You're not using `CreateDIBSection`, you're using `LoadImage`.  Which category the `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` flag puts you into is unclear, but the workaround is clear: **Use `GetDIBits`**.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for GLUT on Windows XP
(tcc or lcc compiler)

```
GLuint LoadTexture(GLuint tex, const char * filename)
{
HBITMAP hBitmap;
BITMAP bm;
HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

//standard bmp 24 bit
//supported resolutions 64x64, 128x128, 256x256, 512x512

//type "char" has a 1 byte size, other types take more byte and will not work
unsigned char * data;
unsigned char R, G, B;

//LoadImage() loads the bmp picture as an interlaced image
hBitmap = LoadImage(NULL, filename, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
    
GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);

//get the address of the start of the image data in memory 
data =  bm.bmBits;

//swap R, G, B values for correct color display

int index, i;

for (i = 0; i < bm.bmWidth * bm.bmHeight ; i++)
    {
    index = i*3;
    B = data[index]; G = data[index+1]; R = data[index+2];
    data[index] = R; data[index+1] = G; data[index+2] = B;
    }

//print image parameters
printf ("bmType %u\n",bm.bmType); 
printf ("bmWidth %u\n",bm.bmWidth); 
printf ("bmHeight %u\n",bm.bmHeight); 
printf ("bmWidthBytes %u\n",bm.bmWidthBytes); 
printf ("bmPlanes %u\n",bm.bmPlanes); 
printf ("bmBitsPixel %u\n",bm.bmBitsPixel); 
printf ("bmBits %p\n",bm.bmBits);
printf ("hInstance %p\n",hInstance);

//create texture from loaded bmp image 
glGenTextures( 1, &tex);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bm.bmBits);

printf ("--- texture %u created ---\n", tex);

//texture filtering
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
}

void init(void)
{
//enable texturing
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
//load texture from bmp 24 bit image file
//bmp exported from mspaint for windows xp
LoadTexture(1, "image1.bmp");
LoadTexture(2, "image2.bmp");
LoadTexture(3, "image3.bmp");
LoadTexture(4, "image4.bmp");
LoadTexture(5, "image5.bmp");
LoadTexture(6, "image6.bmp");
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Compiling.

no cyrilic names, "" for names with spases

tcc C:\tcc\src\box\box.c -o C:\tcc\src\box\box.exe -LC:\tcc\lib -luser32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lglut32 -Wl,-subsystem=console

(without console -Wl,-subsystem=windows)

[image]